# NSXMLParser - Capturing Parent and Child Information ? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have an xml file with a parent child structure such as :

```
<geometry id="001-mesh" name="001">
  <mesh>
    <source id="001-mesh-positions">
      <float_array id="001-mesh-positions-array" count="228">
```

I am able to parse the data successfully using NSXMLParser. However the problem is I want to store the child information in relation to the parent - for example when a geometry id is detected, I then want to store the associated source id and float_array id.

Can anyone suggest a way I could this ? The below code will detect when a given element is found during parsing, but I'm not sure how to then store the values.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

// NSLog(@"Parse Started");
//NSLog(@"Element Name is %@", elementName);

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"geometry"]) { 
    NSLog(@"Object Detected");
    NSString *name = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"name"];

NSLog(@"Name is %@",name);
}

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"float_array"]) {
    NSLog(@"Vertices Detected");
    NSString * vertices = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"count"];

    NSLog(@"Vertices are %@", vertices);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time when the parser detects the `geometry` tag, the source id and float_array id are not available: they have not been parsed yet. The usual trick is to wait for the child element, and do the processing when it becomes available. You can do it by creating a new `Geometry` object (or whatever corresponds to XML's `geometry` tag in your model), and make it available to the `didStartElement:...:` method, for example by setting it into an ivar called `myGeometry`. Once you detect `float_array` element, parse its `id`, and call

```
[myGeometry setId:floatArrayId];
```

Comment: Thanks - but the problem here is that there are other instances of the float_array tag under other parents in the xml file. I only want to create an object if the parent is geometry. Would this be possible ?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco Absolutely: add code to set `myGeometry` to `nil` in the did end element method.

Answer (score 0):

Use either the **class variable** or the **global variable** to hold the current values of geometry id ..