# TBXML parse an only node xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml-parsing, tbxml

I have an xml file having only one node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>Some text here</a>
```

Is possible to use TBXML to parsing it, if possible, please tell me how to implement? Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can parse with `TBXML` like bellow code...

```
TBXMLElement *yourValue = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"a" parentElement:yourParentElement];
```

Comment: Because the parent element is itself. So i wonder how to set? I think this doesn't work

Comment: @DieuLinh put parentelement as a root , try this

Comment: see this tutorial may be you can find something from this link.. http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/API.html

Comment: Thanks, maybe it doesn't support for one node without element xml like this

Comment: also see this que.. if you want to get value from parentelement then pass attribute in this parameter se this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278633/nsxmlparser-capturing-parent-and-child-information-iphone just for get some idea from this que. mate :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19261/discussion-between-dieu-linh-and-paras-joshi)